# How to use eager loading for two controllers in mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller, loading

I have two models and their tables. Restaurant:

> ```
>     public int Id { get; set; }
>     public string Name { get; set; }
>     public string Location { get; set; }
>     public string Image { get; set; }
>     [InverseProperty("Restaurant")]
>     [InverseProperty("Restaurant")]
>     public ICollection<Menu> Menus { get; set; }
> ```

And Menu:

```
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        public int RestaurantId { get; set; }
        public virtual Restaurant Restaurant { get; set; }
```

And I created controller by using EntityFramework with views. I have Restaurant Index view which shows list of restaurants and it has to have menu button in every restaurant info. Also I have Menu Index view which shows menu items. And now my problem is to show menu items which relates to specific restaurant.
RestaurantIndex Actionresult:

> ```
>     public ActionResult Index()
>     {
>         var restaurants = db.Restaurants;
>         return View(restaurants.ToList());
>     }
> ```

MenuIndex ActionResult:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var menus = db.Menus.Include(m => m.Restaurant);
            return View(menus.ToList());

        }
```

That my restaurant's list:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/skGgC.png)
And it is menu:
[but it shows all items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFGhu.png)
I searched about eager loading, but couldn't find similar examples. Can someone tell me how to realize it?

Comment: Do a foreach/ for loop on the view and run through the restaurants and then run through the menu's where the restaurant name == menu.restaurant name

Comment: @JamesS Do you mean this: foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Restaurant.Name)
    </td>
</tr> but it already exists on menu index view

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From looking at the code an the 'images' you have. I would simply pass the `Id` of the restaurant as nullable `int?` into the `Index` of the MenuController such as:

```
public ActionResult Index(int? restaurantId = null)
{
    List<Menu> menus = new List<Menu>();

    if(menuId != null){
        menus = db.Menus.Include(m => m.Restaurant).Where(x => RestaurantId == restaurantId);
    }
    else{
        menus = db.Menus.Include(m => m.Restaurant)
    }

    return View(menus.ToList());
}
```

Then above we filter against the restaurant ID in the controller instead of the view.

In the menu view you should not have to change anything you have done so far.

By having the ID as a nullable parameter, this `Index` method can be called using an ID or not.

Comment: thanks a lot. It worked so well. I 'm new at .net development so I struglled exploring this field

Comment: @GulzhanatZhumazhanova Yeah no problem. Be sure to mark the answer as correct if it helped you out.